# How to change the orientation of a single line (section title) in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

The effect I want to achieve is shown in the figure below. In the example, it is achieved by a text box. But I hope there is a better way in which the structure of article is not "interrupted" by a floating text box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to insert a text box.

If you're using Word 2003, go to `Insert -> Textbox`, and then fill with your text, when you finish just click on it and go to `Format -> Rotate`.

Comment: You do have to use a text box.  However, you can format it to not show a border so it will not intrude on the rest of the text.  Depending on the style you are using, you may want to adjust your margins so it separates the sideways text from the body of your document.

Comment: Vic Abreu, @techturtle, this is what I have done in the example. No better way?